# Regex working on Online but on PHP didn't

Tags: php, regex

I tried match this text with regex

```
&lt;h2&gt;&lt;!-- mp_trans_rt_start id="1" args="as" 5 --&gt;adidas Energy Cloud Mens Trainers&lt;!-- mp_trans_rt_end 5 --&gt;&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;!-- mp_trans_mt_start 208 --&gt;&lt;!-- mp_trans_remove_start="DE,FR,AT" --&gt;
```

I used online tester and it worked with

```
/(&lt;!--.+?--&gt;)/g
```

or

```
/(&lt;!--.*?--&gt;)/g
```

but when I used them in PHP It returns empty array

```
preg_match_all('/(&lt;!--.+?--&gt;)/', $description, $matcheseds);
```

Here is cutted part of my code copy and run it in CLI 
http://pastebin.com/pvnRb8Z1

regex is on the top after definitions

Comment: Works https://3v4l.org/C4QIO

Comment: your code there is same as mine in PHP but it didn't work, it is possible that there is some special char?? and when I copy it from CLI it change to another.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you should write code in a real editor and not in a command prompt.

Comment: I'm writing code in real editor but I'm running it in command as script

Comment: Then it should work just fine.

Comment: I tried another solution (&lt;!--.*?\S*\s*--&gt;) but still empty result

Comment: Are you passing the regex as a command line argument?

Comment: nope regex is coded in script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code I do not see anywhere that the HTML loaded from the web page is being entity-encoded (i.e. < and > converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;`), so  that's why the regex never matches.

Just change your regex to this to look for the raw HTML comment using the unencoded characters:

`preg_match_all('/(<!--.+?-->)/', $description, $matcheseds);`